# TTreeView Vertical Scrollbar Style in RTL Mode

Tags: c++, c++builder, right-to-left, vcl

It seems that there are a lot of problems with right to left mode in windows. I am working to fix some and managed to sort out some and there are some more left to fix in our application. One weird problem I found out is with the vertical scrollbar on a TTreeView control.

When changing the BiDiMode to bdRightToLeft, using SetWindowLong, I have managed to position the content of the TreeView and the vertical scrollbar correctly:

```
if (TreeView2->BiDiMode == bdRightToLeft)
{
     LONG ExStyle = GetWindowLong(TreeView2->Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE);
     SetWindowLong(TreeView2->Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_RTLREADING | WS_EX_RIGHT | WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL | WS_EX_NOINHERITLAYOUT);
}
```

However, the scrollbar loses the custom style as seen in attached image.

[image]

Any ideas how to fix this. Is creating a custom TScrollingStyleHook the right/only way to fix this?

Edit: Still not able to fix this. Subsequent questions:

- What method of TTreeView or TTreeViewStyleHook draws the text of each
  node?
- It appears that TreeViewStyleHook.Paint or
  TScrollingStyleHook.Paint is never called. Why would that be?

Thanks

IDE Version Info: Embarcadero C++Builder 10.2 Version 25.0.27659.1188

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the VCL. Did you [report it to Embarcadero](http://quality.embarcadero.com)?

Comment: Yes. With bunch of other issues that we have created workarounds for. CategoryPanelGroup scrollbar, tabs direction, status bar sizing grip... Some of the fixes are so easy at the VCL level but we are linking runtime libs. I think I have figured this one out. I will reply if I get it working.